# Trying to add numbers in python loop wrong result

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to write a program that counts a range of values but for multiples of 3 and 4 adds 3 and 4 to them resepectively and when the number is multiple of both adds that number to it. So for instance 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
should read in the end program as: 1,2,6,8,5,9,7,12,10,11,24

But my code is getting stuck somewhere.

```
for i in range (1,20):
   if i%3==0 and i%4==0:
       i=i+12
   if i%3==0:
       i=i+3
   if i%4==0:
       i=i+4
   print i
```

Comment: You may want to use the `+=` syntax as well. Instead of `i=i+4`, you could use `i+=4`. It'll make it cleaner.

Comment: Please note my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better (accurate and cleaner) if you use a different variable.

```
for i in range (1,20):
   n = i
   if i%3==0 and i%4==0:
       n=i+12
   if i%3==0:
       n=i+3
   if i%4==0:
       n=i+4
   print n
```

Now you will notice this fixed it for the 9 case, but not the 12 case! We now need to add the use of `elif`. Also, if a number is a multiple of 3 and 4, then it is also a multiple of their lowest common multiple, in this case 12. So you could re-write your first step to just check for multiples of 12. This gives us:

```
for i in range (1,20):
   n = i
   if i%12==0
       n=i+12 # or possibly i + i
   elif i%3==0:
       n=i+3
   elif i%4==0:
       n=i+4
   print n
```

The reason this works is because without the `elif` the i was getting added to multiple times. For example, with 9, you get to `9%3 ==0`, True. Now i is set to 12. Next statement? `12%4 ==0` True. So another 4 is added.

Alternatively, if you would like to do some crazy python stuff:

```
for i in range(1, 20):
    print i + next((n for n in (12, 4, 3) if i % n == 0), 0)
```

(Shout out to Jon Clements for this 2-liner answer)

Answer (score 3):

This line has a typo

```
if i%3==0 and 1%4==0:  # your second condition is 1 % 4 == 0, which is always false
```

I think you meant

```
if i%3==0 and i%4==0:
```

Answer (score 1):

You're allowing multiples cases (if conditions) for each iteration.
I think you probably wanted to do exclusive cases.

Maybe something like:

```
for i in range(1, 20):
    print i, "=>",
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 4 == 0:
        i += i
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        i += 3
    elif i % 4 == 0:
        i += 4
    print i
```